# SQL tricky order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

i'm trying to order a returned set, but i'm having a hard time getting it to order properly.

i'm selecting fields, and each field has a `date_updated` and a `date_added`.
when the field is added, the `date_updated` is null, until there is an update, which it then assigns the current date.

i need to order my list by having the most recent entries be on the BOTTOM, and oldest on the top. so if a item is added, it should go directly to the bottom. is there a way to join all the date fields together, and then just sort by oldest to newest, disregarding update or added?

this may sound kind of confusing, but i've already tried numerous combinations of `ORDER BY date_added DESC, date_updated ASC`, and things like that, but it's not doing what I need it to do. i get the top portion ordered by `date_added` and then under that is a separate ordering for `date_updated`...

any input would be really helpful here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
order by coalesce(date_updated, date_added)
```

[COALESCE DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement

```
SELECT 
    firstname, 
    lastname, 
    date_added, 
    date_updated, 
    CASE date_updated IS NULL 
        THEN date_added 
        ELSE date_updated 
    END CASE AS order_date  
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY order_date DESC
```

What this does is it checks if `date_updated` is null and then puts in the new column the value of `date_added`. If not, it puts the `date_updated`. The new column is called `order_date` and is used for sorting.

You can also add the CASE statement in the ORDER BY clause but that might slow your query down since it has to do the concatenation on the index vs. when constructing the data. Although not conclusive, I have found a slight performance gain if the CASE is used in the SELECT vs. the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` in `Order By` Clause.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN date_updated IS NULL
              THEN 0 
              ELSE 1
          END DESC, date_added DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Order by IsNull(DateUpdated,DateAdded)
```

would be one way